# Configure the way file ID attribute is generated on Shrine gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, shrine

Shrine creates a random `ID` for the uploaded file to AWS S3 when calling `presign_endpoint`. Is there a way to change the way the `ID` is generated using Shrine's configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`:presign_location`](https://shrinerb.com/docs/plugins/presign_endpoint#location):

```
Shrine.plugin :presign_endopint, presign_location: -> (request) do
  "#{SecureRandom.hex}/#{request.params["filename"]}" # for example
end
```